# Another elementary log inequality

Tags: inequality

I came across this as a part of an answer to a exercise:

$$(n + \frac{1}{2}) \log(1 + \frac{1}{n}) - 1\gt 0$$

for $n\gt 0$, where $n$ is a real.

How do you prove this? I tried some Taylor approximations for $\log$ but they don't work because they cross $0$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let
$$
f(x)=\Bigl(x + \frac{1}{2}\Bigr) \log\Bigl(1 + \frac{1}{n}\Bigr) - 1,\quad x>0.
$$
Then
$$
f''(x)=\frac{1}{2\,x^2\,(x+1)^2}>0,
$$
so that $f$ is convex. Moreover
$$
\lim_{x\to0^+}f(x)=+\infty\text{ and }\lim_{x\to\infty}f(x)=0.
$$
This is only possible if $f(x)>0$ for all $x>0$.

Comment: Thanks I get the intuition behind the last step but is there a name for it?

Comment: If $f(x)<0$ for some $x$, then $f$ would attain a negative minimum, say at $a$. Then $f'(a)=0$, $f''(a)ºle0$. But this is impossible, since $f''>0$.

Answer (score 2):

You just need this easy corollary of the mean value theorem:

> Let $f,\, g$ be functions differentiable on an interval $I$ and $x_0\in I$. Suppose $f(x_0)\ge g(x_0$ and $f'(x)> g'(x)$ if $x > x_0$, $x\in I$. Then
>   $$f(x) > g(x)\quad\text{for all}\enspace x>x_0,\; x\in I.$$

Indeed, the inequality is equivalent to $\;\log\Bigl(1+\dfrac1n\Bigr)>\dfrac2{2n+1}=\dfrac2{n\Bigl(2+\cfrac1n\Bigr)}$.

Setting $x=\dfrac1n$, all we have to do is to compare the derivatives of the  functions $f(x)=\log(1+x)$ and $\;g(x)=\dfrac{2x}{2+x}$:
$$f'(x)>g'(x)\iff \frac1{1+x}>\frac4{(2+x)^2}\iff (2+x)^2>4+4x\iff x^2>0$$
As $f(0)=g(0)$, the assertion results from the corollary.

Answer (score 0):

Why donot you try binomial theorem:
$(n+1/2)log(1+1/n)$

$=log(1+1/n)^{n+1/2}...mlogn=logm^n$
$=log(1+1/n)^n.(1+1/n)^{1/2}
...(logmn=logm+logn)$

$=log(1+1/n)^n+(1/2)log(1+1/n)$

$=loge+1/2(positive quantity)>1$

Comment: I don't see how the first step works.

Comment: I don't see why $\log(1 + 1/n)^n = e$ for each $n > 0$, except for when $n \to \infty$.

Answer (score 0):

Rewriting the inequality, we want to show that:

\begin{equation*}
\exp\Big[\log \big(1+\frac{1}{n}\big)\, \big(n + \frac{1}{2}\big)\Big] > e.
\end{equation*}

It is immediate that the LHS is:

\begin{equation*}
\Big( 1 + \frac{1}{n} \Big) ^{n + 1/2} = \Big(1 + \frac{1}{n}\Big)^n \Big(1 + \frac{1}{n}\Big)^{1/2} > \Big(1 + \frac{1}{n}\Big)^n,
\end{equation*}
which tends to $e$ as $n \to \infty$. It remains to prove that the sequence $\big\{(1 + 1/n)^n\big\}_{n=0}^\infty$ is non-increasing. We form the difference:
\begin{equation*}
\begin{split}
\Big(1 + \frac{1}{n}\Big)^n - \Big(1 + \frac{1}{n+1}\Big)^{n+1} &= \Big(1 + \frac{1}{n}\Big)^n - \Big(1 + \frac{1}{n+1}\Big)^n \Big(1 + \frac{1}{n+1}\Big)\\
&\geq \Big(1 + \frac{1}{n}\Big)^n - \Big(1 + \frac{1}{n}\Big)^n \Big(1 + \frac{1}{n+1}\Big)\\
&= \Big(1 + \frac{1}{n}\Big)^n \Big(\frac{1}{n+1}\Big) > 0,
\end{split}
\end{equation*}
which shows that the sequence is indeed non-decreasing.

I hope I haven't made any mistake.

Comment: Sorry should've been clearer but $n$ isn't necessarily an integer here.